# Describing Linear transformation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

For each of the following linear transformations, write down its matrix and describe the transformation

a) $g(x,y)=(4x,6y)$

b) $h(x,y)=(x+2y,y)$

c) $k(x,y)=(y,x)$

So I have worked out the matrices:

$\begin{bmatrix}
4 &  0  \\
0  & 6   
\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &  2  \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
 0   & 1  \\
1 & 0   
\end{bmatrix}$

Not sure what the transformations would be?

Comment: you are correct!

Comment: For example, for the first case the transformation is $$T\binom xy=\begin{pmatrix}4&0\\0&6\end{pmatrix}\binom xy$$

Comment: Next time use:http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

The "describe" part is asking you what each transformation does to the input $(x,y)$; think of this as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For example, a transformation that sends $(x,y)$ to $(-x,y)$ is a reflection over the $y$-axis.

Start with the transformation $k$; that has a nice "symmetry".

Answer (score 0):

You would describe g as stretching plane in the x-direction by a factor 4 and in the y-direction by a factor of 6.